# Most efficient way to store this collection of moduli and remainders?

Tags: data-structures, efficiency

I have a huge collection of different moduli and associated with each modulus a fairly large list of remainders. I want to store these values so that I can efficiently determine whether an integer is equivalent to any one of the remainders with respect to any of the moduli (it doesn't matter which, I just want a true/false return).

I thought about storing these values as a linked-list of balanced binary trees, but I was wondering if there is a better way?

**EDIT**

Perhaps a little more detail would be helpful. As for the size of this structure, it will be holding about 10s of thousands of (prime-1) moduli and associated to each modulus will be a variable amount of remainders. Most moduli will only have one or two remainders associated to it, but a very rare few will have a couple hundred associated to it.

This is part of a larger program which handles numbers with a couple thousand (decimal) digits. This program will benefit more from this table being as large as possible and being able to be searched quickly.

Here's a small part of the dataset where the moduli are in parentheses and the remainders are comma separated:

```
(46) k = 20
(58) k = 15, 44    
(70) k = 57        
(102) k = 36, 87    
(106) k = 66        
(156) k = 20, 59, 98, 137     
(190) k = 11, 30, 68, 87, 125, 144, 182 
(430) k = 234
(520) k = 152, 282
(576) k = 2, 11, 20, 29, 38, 47, 56, 65, 74, ...(add 9 each time), 569
```

I had said that the moduli were prime, but I was wrong they are each one below a prime.

Comment: A map of sets, with the keys being moduli, and the sets containing the remainders?

Comment: I want to be able to quickly tell if an integer is sent to any remainder with respect to any of my moduli. With that kind of map implementation, I would still have to cycle through the keys to see if a remainder is associated to a key. I don't see how that's better than what I was already contemplating.

Comment: Have you ever checked out [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)? Depending on the scale of this problem you might find something like this useful...

Comment: @JTrana that is very interesting, and I'll keep it in mind for the future; however in terms of probabilistic structures, something which gives false positives is unacceptable for the structure I'm trying to implement. Also, true positives are very desirable.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you build up the structure you're testing against statically? Or do you need to update it while you're doing tests against it...?

Comment: It's static once I initialize it.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood and thought you wanted to know if the integer was a remainder for a specific modulus. To be clear, by modulus you mean the `5` in `17 % 5 = 2`, correct? And by determine if an integer is equivalent to a remainder with respect to a modulus, you mean e.g. 17 is equivalent to the remainder 2 with respect to 5?

Comment: Yes. It might help (or not) to know that all the moduli are also prime.

Comment: Are you testing whether the integer is prime?

Comment: No, I am not. I know there are algorithms for prime-testing that don't require this much preprocessing.

Comment: Could you post a small example dataset?  I'm having a hard time visualizing this.

Comment: I don't understand whats the point of this. Can you explain what is supposed to be input of and output of algorithm you need?

Comment: The algorithm takes as input a (positive) integer, and the output is a boolean value which says whether or not my input is equivalent to any one of the remainders with respect to any one of the moduli. I want a way to store the moduli and remainders to efficiently implement this algorithm.

Comment: What about a heap of balanced binary trees? Where the values of the elements of the heap are the balanced binary trees and the keys of the elements are the total nodes in the tree?

Comment: @Bryan - Two more questions.  I have a few ideas, but I want to clarify what's best.  First, do you actually care about keeping the moduli at all?  Or can you just keep a list of remainders?  Second, are you going to be adding to the list dynamically, or is it going to be a load-once-read-frequently scenario?

Comment: If we can throw away the moduli while keeping the intended functionality, that's fine. And it is a load-once-read-frequently scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be to parse the data as you read it in, and throw away what you don't need.  Since you don't care *which* modulus a given remainder corresponds to, or how many times a given remainder shows up, you can just keep a list of remainders.

In pseudocode, building this might look something like:

```
while (data = ReadNextModulus())
   foreach (rem in data.Remainders)
      if !allRemainders.HasRemainder(rem) // We do this check because presumably lookups are faster 
         allRemainders[rem] = true        // than inserts, so we want to skip the insert if possible.
```

Then when you're done and actually using it, you just check `allRemainders.HasRemainder(rem)`.

In terms of the best data structure to store this, I don't have any specific recommendations myself, but I can point you in the right direction.  You're going to have a list of `int` values which you need fast lookup for.  The naive implementation would be to store it as an unsorted array of `int`s.  This would have [`O(n)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) time.  If you sorted it before using it, that'd reduce to `O(log n)`, presuming you use a binary search.

There's other options out there, though.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11299092/298754) talks about it.  The answers suggest trying a [Van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree), a bitmap, or just the previously discussed sorted array.  You'll need to take a look at them, consider the sparseness of the data you have, and what your language of choice has as built in data structures, and pick the one you think will be best.

But the key is that you're just storing **whether a given remainder has been seen, not the full data structure**.

Comment: If I've thrown away the moduli, when I put in an integer which is outside the range (greater than any) of the moduli how will I tell its equivalent to any of the remainders? Wouldn't I have to perform a mod test for every integer that was below my limit to see if it's equivalent to any of the remainders, and not just the moduli I cared about?

Comment: @Bryan - I'm not 100% sure I'm following you, but you can always just store the single largest moduli in a separate variable.

Comment: What would have been your recommendation if I wanted to keep the moduli? But just so you know, I settled on a 'splay list' of balance binary trees. Each binary tree represented the remainders associated to a certain modulus. And whenever I tested an integer, I looped through the trees taking mods and searching that tree for the remainders. The first tree I found that matched my test integer was moved to the front of the list.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't mind which reminder the integer is related to and I see 87 is duplicated (and you will count only once), you could use a unique structure to store theese values. 
A boolean array gives you O(1) complexity to find if an element exists or not (if you know the maximum dimention and you can have it all in RAM).
If also theese values can have thousands of digits and RAM is not enought you should use structures as tree (eg. B-trees) to have O(log n) complexity (the height of the tree).